# How do I explictly collect a vector of itertools::MinMaxResult?

Tags: rust

I'm using the `minmax` function from the itertools crate:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let row_minmax: Vec<MinMaxResult> = input
    .into_par_iter()
    .map(|row| row.iter().minmax())
    .collect::<Vec<MinMaxResult>>();
```

I get:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `MinMaxResult` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:25
  |
4 |     let row_minmax: Vec<MinMaxResult> = input
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
help: possible candidate is found in another module, you can import it into scope
  |
1 | use itertools::MinMaxResult;
```

I've tried replacing `MinMaxResult` with `itertools::MinMaxResult` and variants thereupon, to no effect:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:4:25
  |
4 |     let row_minmax: Vec<itertools::MinMaxResult> = input
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

I am aware that I can use `Vec<_>`, but I am very new to Rust, so I prefer to explicitly type everything (even if it is not idiomatic) to make sure that what goes through my head correlates with what the compiler is doing. I know this makes the code look like sick, but it helps me learn.

Comment: `itertools::MinMaxResult` is a generic type, you would need to specify a type, for example `itertools::MinMaxResult<u32>`.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thank you! If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You need to re-evaluate whatever tool you are using to make sure it shows the *complete* errors. They guide you to the solution.

Comment: Please do not put *answers* in your *question*. You are welcome to answer your own question below and even accept that answer. This is better because it allows additional answers and those answers to be voted on by the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itertools::MinMaxResult` is a generic type. You need to either specify the type parameter, or use `_` to let the compiler infer it.

```
let row_minmax = input
    .into_par_iter()
    .map(|row| row.iter().minmax())
    .collect::<Vec<MinMaxResult<u32>>>();
```